# add new item to dropdownlist in datalist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a Datalist and I'm trying to find the `dropdown` in the `datalist` to add in it text in first index in `ddl` I tried to do that but this appeared (`object reference not set` ....)

**Here is my code:**

```
private  DropDownList DDLProduct;
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
 protected void DDlProduct_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DDLProduct.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Swithch Model", "0"));
    }
 protected void DLProduct_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {


        DDLProduct = e.Item.FindControl("DDlProduct") as DropDownList;


    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
  protected void DLProduct_ItemDataBound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
  {

     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
         e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
     {

        private  DropDownList DDLProduct = e.Item.FindControl("DDlProduct") as DropDownList;
        DDLProduct.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Swithch Model", "0"));

     }

  }
```

Comment: oops its pretty much what jonh says :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check the ItemDataBound event for the datalist and see if it is of type ListItemType.Item or ListItemType.AlternatingItem, otherwise you are hitting the null reference because you are on the header of the datalist:

in C#:

`if ((e.item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) | (e.item.itemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))`

in VB.net:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) OR (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
```

Then you want to see if you can find it:

in C#:

`DropDownList d = (DropDownList) e.Item.FindControl("DDLProduct")`

in vb.net

`Dim d as DropDownList = CType(e.Item.FindControl("DDLProduct"), DropDownList)`

Once you have found the dropdownlist box you can do:

```
d.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Switch Model", "0"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need [AppendDataBoundItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put you code within below if statement.

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {

     // Your code goes here to find the drop down list.      
}
```

You are getting the null reference exception because of header of footer rows, as this drop down is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it's working:

```
sQuery = "select * from tbl_Ticket_Msg where us_ID=0 and t_status='Open' order by T_id asc";
        ds3.Clear();
        ds3 = cl.getDataSet(sQuery);
        if (ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataList1.DataSource = ds3.Tables[0];
            DataList1.DataBind();
            lbltotal.Text = "Total Messages : " + ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();

            int row = Convert.ToInt32(ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                DropDownList ddl =  (DropDownList)DataList1.Items[i].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                ddl.DataSource = BindServicetoddl();
                ddl.DataTextField = "name1";
                ddl.DataValueField = "us_ID";
                ddl.DataBind();
            }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
```